# Identify this brownie-like dessert

Tags: food-identification

When I was a kid, there was a dessert that would frequently be at pot-lucks that was a brownie-like dessert. It's been a long time since I had it so don't remember the details exactly but it was like a brownie with a greenish mint cream/marshmallow layer on top and then a thin chocolate layer on top of that.  I'd love to make it again but have no idea where to find the recipe.  Does anyone know what this dessert would be called?

Comment: Recipe requests are off topic, but your question for identifying the dish is on topic

Comment: No problem! Assuming my answer to identify it is correct (or someone else helps identify it), you should be able to find a recipe easily enough. Then if you have any problems with that recipe not meeting the ones you remember, come on back with targeted questions to make them...fluffier, denser, mintier, or whatever. Good luck! Nostalgic cooking is the best kind!

Comment: It sounds like a Nanaimo bar except for the creamy layer being green and minty. A search for "mint Nanaimo bar" might get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a "Grasshopper brownie" which is a sort of "grasshopper pie and brownie mashup" dessert.

Grasshopper pie is a chocolate crust pie with mint cream filling. And for grasshopper brownies, it lends that minty cream filling to a layered brownie variation.

[image: grasshopper brownies]

Comment: Been meaning to come back and mark this as the solution.  Made these and they were awesome.  Also made a couple of variations on it as well.  Thanks again